# Какой компонент нужно скачать для дальнейшего создания проектов win32? C++

Tags: c++, winapi

У меня Visual Studio 2019. Какой компонент мне необходимо скачать, чтобы создавать в дальнейшем проекты win32. Я пробовал писать в пустом проекте, с подключенной библиотекой , но ничего не выходит, слишком много ошибок.

Comment: Вам нужен не волшебный компонент из интернета, который исправит все ошибки, а просто надо разобраться со студией.

Comment: И еще не надо несколько раз задавать один и тот же вопрос.

Comment: Запусти инсталлятор Студии и отметь чекбокс Desktop development with C++. Нажми Modify. [тыц](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/support/hello-world-in-c-using-visual-studio-2019/)